# ListView with EditText View Issue

Tags: android

I have ListView which contains text and EditText to write.

Here my problem is while clicking on item which is at bottom i am unable to see the editText,

So any please suggest me how to scroll up the total when keyboard appears.

Thanks.

Comment: Just in your application's manifest file in activity tag put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` ...

Comment: +1 agree with @user370305, and if possible then also want possible snap of issue you are facing.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" is not working @user370305

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will set a xml params "android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" to the EditText's ParentView.

Comment: But sometimes keyboard is not appearing on click of the edittext box